# Connection to Oracle Database Via an API Settings File

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I'm trying to learn API's as we have a business case for it. and for the most part I can read and Serialize/Deserialize the data from our Oracle database - HOWEVER, in order to connect to the database im hardcoding the connectionString variable at the top of the page  e.g

```
con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=my.oracle.host)(PORT=9999)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=myOracleService)));User Id=XXXXXX;Password=XXXXXX; ");
```

Ive created the OracleSettingsDB.cs file as below

```
public class OracleDbSettings{

        public string Host{get;set;}

        public string Port{get;set;}

        public string User{get;set;}

        public string Password{get;set;}

        public string Service{get;set;}

        public string ConnectionString{

            get
            {
                return $"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST={Host})(PORT={Port})))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME={Service})));User Id={User};Password={Password};";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and following on from that added the values to the appsettings.json

````
"AllowedHosts": "*",
  "OracleDbSettings": {
      "Host": "my.oracle.host",
      "Port":"9999",
      "User": "XXXXX",
      "Service":"myOracleService",
      "Password": "XXXXXX"  //Yes I know I shouldnt store this here
  }```

I added the connectionString into the Startup.cs

``` var connectionString = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(OracleDbSettings)).Get<OracleDbSettings>();
````

But what I dont now get is how i reference the connectionString within the Repository file so that I can call

`using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString)`

Hopefully, someone will be able to point me in the right direction as all the videos Ive watched on Youtube or pages ive found just reference the hardcoded data source - which we dont want to do.

Thanks and Hopefully theres enough information there =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you need to bind the values in `appsettings.json` file to your `OracleDbSettings` model, and I find [similar document](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/ODPNET_Core_get_started/index.html) about how to connect to oracle which matches your `using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString)`, so I provide the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#bind-hierarchical-configuration-data-using-the-options-pattern-1) here to solve your requirement. And this is my test details:

I newly created an asp.net core 5 mvc project and create a model like yours:

```
namespace WebMvcApp.Models
{
    public class OracleDbSettings
    {
        public const string keyword = "OracleDbSettings";
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public string Port { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Service { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return $"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST={Host})(PORT={Port})))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME={Service})));User Id={User};Password={Password};";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Modify the startup.cs file-> Configure method, and adding these line-code:

```
var dbSettings = new OracleDbSettings();
Configuration.GetSection(OracleDbSettings.keyword).Bind(dbSettings);
var connect_string = dbSettings.ConnectionString;
```

And my appsettings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "OracleDbSettings": {
    "Host": "my.oracle.host",
    "Port": "9999",
    "User": "XXXXX",
    "Service": "myOracleService",
    "Password": "XXXXXX"
  }
}
```

[image]